# How would I get more than 200 Smart_Campaigns using Marketo Bulk Extract API?

Tags: python, api, adobe, marketo

[get_smart_campaign (Marketo API)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8yu.png)

Hi all,

The picture above is currently the process I am using to extract Smart_Campaign data using the .execute() method. It returns all the smart campaigns listed up to 200 objects. I have over 3000 objects that I need to get but the API limits are complicating the process.

I read about the Marketo Bulk Extract API but I am not sure if I will be able to extract the smart_campaign id and name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your own words, where it says `maxReturn=200`, what do you suppose that means? Did you try changing the `200` there to some other number? What effect does that have? Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, don't just tell us things like "I read about the Marketo Bulk Extract API". Show us the relevant portion of what you read, by quoting it in the question, and then clearly and specifically explain why you are "unsure".